# Transmit variables from service at onDestroy() to already opened Main-Activity

Tags: android, variables, service, android-activity, bundle

I have a Main-Activity which displays several spinners.
With a Toggle-Button in the Main-Activity I start a service which collects GPS-Data in background that measures the distance and sets some other variables.
When I stop the service with another click on the Toggle-Button in the Main-Activity, I stop the service, so the onDestroy() command is executed in the Service.
Within onDestroy in the Service, I want to submit the variables from the service to the already opened Main-Activity.
I tried that so far without success in the service:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    Test = 2222;
    b.putInt("Test", Test);
    intent.putExtras(b);
```

I do not use the "startActivity(intent);", cause the activity that should the data send to is already open...the Main-Activity.

And on the side of the Main-Activity:

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null){ 
       Test = b.getInt("Test");
    }
    else{
       //..oops!
       Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Oops...Nothing from service! :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I never get data from the service.
I am trying this cause I need to start the service from the Main-Activity, from the Main activity the user stops the service and gets the values from it, then the Main-Activity should transmit the values from the service AND from the selected spinner values from itself to another activity.

I am trying that now for days and I also find some hints here, but nothing worked for me so far.
Someone any ideas?
Do I have to use a Broadcast-Receiver?
Whats the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before destroying the service store the data in shared preference and access it in the main activity

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way, but just have the Service you created update a static pojo. If the activity is already open then you could just set a timer to poll a the static pojo from the Activity to see if something has changed through an AsyncTask. When something has been updated in the pojo the AsyncTask can tell the Activity to update the UI accordingly. Then you don't have to play around with silly bundles. Also if your worried about your data getting lost you could always use SQLite. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need a broadcast receiver in main activity to get the data.